# Is the algebra of differential operators of finite degree globally generated by the operators of degree at most $1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-operators

Let $M$ be a smooth real manifold and let $D_{< \infty}(M)$ be the algebra of differential operators of finite degree on $M$; it is the union $\bigcup_n D_{\leq n}(M)$ of the sets of differential operators of degree at most $n \in \mathbb N$.

I have two closely related questions:

> 1. Locally (on coordinate neighborhoods) $D_{< \infty}$ is generated as an $\mathbb R$-algebra by $D_{\leq 1}$. (I.e. by vector fields and smooth functions.) Is this true globally?
> 2. (Stronger) Is each $D_{\leq n}$ globally generated as an $\mathbb R$-module by $(D_{\leq 1})^n$?

If $M$ has a finite partition of unity with each support contained in a coordinate neighborhood, this is true. In particular it is true for compact $M$.

---

I'm interested in this because, for example, the pullback would then be the unique extension as an algebra-isomorphism of the pullback on vector fields and functions.

Comment: Why do you need a finite partition? Would a locally finite partition work? Iirc those always exist.

Comment: @AreaMan Because in an algebra we can only take finite sums. While the infinite sum in this case is locally finite, it's still an infinite sum.

Comment: If you allow for disconnected charts, then every manifold has a finite atlas. Wouldn't this solve the problem, as the local considerations work on disconnected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well?

Comment: @JanBohr It's not obvious to me even whether it holds on a countable disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb R$...